# Is there any way to programmatically set the selection of a spinner by it's name?

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to figure this one out for a while now, but no matter how much I look, I haven't found an answer. So far I've checked the following questions: [Set selected item of spinner programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072576/set-selected-item-of-spinner-programmatically), [How to set selected item of Spinner by value, not by position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390102/how-to-set-selected-item-of-spinner-by-value-not-by-position), and [How to set position in spinner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769368/how-to-set-position-in-spinner). So far none of them have worked for me. I'm trying to do this on Android 4.4.2, and here's my code:

```
String dataReturned11 = someData.getString("unitCheckFour", "degrees F");
if (dataReturned11 == ("degrees C")) {
    tempUnits.setSelection(((ArrayAdapter<String>)tempUnits.getAdapter()).getPosition("degrees C"));
} else {
    tempUnits.setSelection(((ArrayAdapter<String>)tempUnits.getAdapter()).getPosition("degrees F"));
};
```

What I'm trying to do is set it based on a value that was saved earlier, and it doesn't seem to be working. An important thing to note is that this gave me an unchecked cast warning, so I suppressed it. It does not seem to have had any effect on my problem whatsoever.

EDIT: Since it was asked for, here is the code behind the spinner itself:

```
tempUnits = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.tempUnits);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter4 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    R.array.tempUnits, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter4.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
tempUnits.setAdapter(adapter4);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: can u post how u construct the spinner & the arrayAdapter?

Comment: if u haven`t specify the type of ArrayAdapter, getPosition() might return -1. in that case, setSelection dose not work

Comment: Make a global variable of your adapter and init your adapter before setSelection then use tempUnits.setSelection(adapter4.getPosition(dataReturned11);

Answer (score 0):

yes you can .

```
 for (int i=0;i<projectArray.size();i++)
    {
        if (projectArray.get(i).getName().equals(tasksArray.get(position).getProject()))
        {
            project.setSelection(i);
            return;
        }
    }
```