# How to scroll Spinner to specific position when dropdown menu appears?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-spinner

I want to scroll my `Spinner` to specific position when user clicks on it. There are more than 50 items in it. That means I want to add initial position to almost top of the dropdown menu.

Tried this, doesnt work.

```
spinner?.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
            v.scrollTo(v.scrollX, 0)
            v.performClick()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`setSelection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner#setSelection(int)).

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10161277/1231245

Comment: I dont want to select item in list, I want to scroll to specific position at start (without selecting option in Spinner header (or how to call it))